# Save check constraint values to variables

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I get a table check constraint definition this way:

```
select a.CHECK_CLAUSE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS a,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS b
where b.TABLE_NAME = 'table name'
```

For my example, suppose running this query returns this:

```
[([depname]='mathematics' OR [depname]='electronics' OR [depname]='computer science')]
```

**How do I assign the values ​​specified in the check constraint into variables? i.e. computer science, mathematics and electronics?**

Comment: You would have to declare the variables up front, so do you know if there are going to be 3, 15 or 237 OR clauses in there?

Comment: Number of OR clauses is not clear.It depends on table and column that used.

Comment: Right, so how are you going to declare your variables? And what are you going to do with them? Maybe you want to put the values into a table variable or #temp table instead of individual variables...

Comment: Can you clarify what you are going to do with this result, and where you will process it?

Comment: I want to construct graph of my data base and these values will be nodes of graph that is relate to node correspond to  parent table.

Comment: It will process in java

Comment: Then I suggest you parse/split the string in Java, not in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a string returned. What you can do is split the string on instances of `OR` and store that in an array, and then run through the array and split each element on `=` to isolate the values. So, if you were to do this in PHP, the code might look something like this:

```
// For reasons of simplicity we will assume the result is stored in $result,
// and the leading [( and trailing )] have already been removed
$values = array();
$resultsplit = explode(' OR ', $result);

/* $resultsplit is now an array:
 * $resultsplit[0] = "[depname]='mathematics'"
 * $resultsplit[1] = "[depname]='electronics'"
 * $resultsplit[2] = "[depname]='computer science'"
 */

if ($result != '') {
    foreach ($resultsplit as $rs) {
        $rsparts = explode('=', $rs);

        /* $rsparts is now an array. On the first element:
         * $rsparts[0] = "[depname]"
         * $rsparts[1] = "'mathematics'"
         * So all we need to do is stick $rsparts[1] into $values
         */

        $values[] = $rsparts[1];
    }
}
```

This will put all of the values into the array `$values` (including the single-quotes at the beginning and end) for you to do with as you please, regardless of how many there are. If PHP is not the language you have available to you, the same method should still work in your language of choice.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have arrays (or a built-in split mechanism), so "your language of choice" is actually a lot more limiting than you make it sound. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm presuming that since he wants to put them into variables, he has access to another language in which to parse the results. If that ends up not being the case, I will likely remove this answer as irrelevant.